# spring-social-twitter, @Value not wiring attribute

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, twitter

While extending Spring Twitter Social, I'm using **application-test.properties** and I can't get @Value to autowire the properties into some fields.

**DETAILS OF THE ISSUE**

```
@Value("${spring.social.twitter.hosts.ads-api}")
private String baseUrlApiAds;

@Value("${spring.social.twitter.hosts.standard-api}")
private String baseUrlApiStandard;
```

***application-test.properties* in src/test/resources:**

```
# spring-social-twitter
spring.social.twitter.hosts.standard-api : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
spring.social.twitter.hosts.ads-api      : https://ads-api-sandbox.twitter.com/0/
```

However, inside my spring-social-twitter extension (the one Im mentioned for Spring Social Twitter), the values are never bound.

I have also tried to get the parameters into the *application.properties*, no luck too...

This is the top of the declaration of my integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:9003")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Application.class, IntegrationConfig.class })
@ActiveProfiles(IntegrationConfig.PROFILE_TEST)
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
}
```

Could anybody give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class which is using `@Value` annotation seems to be not getting initialised by the spring. If the spring initialises the class, it should pick up the values with `@Value` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Above integration test, can you please try putting this annotation:

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-test.properties")`

Mke sure that the file is present in classpath, and the class which has @Value annotations is initialised by the spring.

Comment: Hey @shruti1810, I have just tested to confirm: **it does not solve the problem**.

my **application-test.properties** is for sure being loaded. I know that, because there are properties there without which the test would not even load up. Additionally, "application-test.properties" load by default when using Spring Boot loader, because of this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I was asking you to use "=" as your value also has ":". Btw, how did you verify that the application-test.properties are getting loaded?

Comment: yes, it is @shruti1810! I double checked it. There's properties there that my application wouldn't even launch the tests otherwise. Like: the server.port to register my Mvc app in Tomcat (Spring Boot) requires that. And if I delete application-test.properties, tests do not even launch.

Comment: Is the class in which these properties are present initialised by the spring?

Comment: That is a very good question @shruti1810. They are part of Spring-Social-Twitter. So I believe that the answer is YES, but I have no confirmation about it so far.

Comment: you were correct, @shruti1810. Spring does not initialize any of the Spring Social Twitter classes. Therefore, there's no "Value autowiring" there. Please do add an answer, so I can mark this as solved.

Comment: @hudsonmendes Added another answer. Will delete this answer once you mark the other one correct.

Comment: @shruri1810 done, but it's cool to leave it as a log for people who are landing to the question. Cheers!

Comment: @hudsonmendes Cool.. will leave this as it is. Thanks.